# Php/MySQL group movies into chapters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a series of movies about some topic. I store them in a table in my database:

```
ID Title 

1 Intorduction to anger management
2 The emotional life
3 What is anger
4 Why anger is important
5 Noticing anger
6 Using an anger meter
7 The aggression cycle
```

I want to display this list on a website, but to make it more friendly, i would like to present it chapters like so:

```
1. Introduction
   1.1 Introduction to anger management
2. Anger is important
   2.1 The emotional life
   2.2 What is anger
   2.3 Why anger is important
3. Basic awareness
   3.1 Noticing anger
   3.2 Using an anger meter
   3.3 The aggression cycle
```

So basically I'd like to group the movies into chapters and give names to the chapters. Also it would be great if I could have some power over deciding the order of movies in the chapter (later i might want to add a movie that i would like to appear in between existing movies in a chapter). What is the best idea to go around that in PHP/MySQL?

Thanks,
Albert

Comment: Just use a simple php loop, acting upon an ordered array. Lots of tutorials out there

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional field to movies table like ChapterId, where you will store Id of chapter, and also additional table with ChapterID's and their names.

After that you can easily build in PHP pretty same multi-level list as you shown via normal loop over result of SELECT from this tables.